# jest can not find external library in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jestjs

I have a `nextjs` app using `jest`.

My `jest.config.js` file is:

```
const nextJest = require('next/jest')

const createJestConfig = nextJest({
  // Provide the path to your Next.js app to load next.config.js and .env files in your test environment
  dir: '.',
})

// Add any custom config to be passed to Jest
const customJestConfig = {
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],
  testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
  collectCoverageFrom: ['src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!(ky)/)',
  ],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/', '/dist/'],
  moduleDirectories: [
    "node_modules"
  ],
}

// createJestConfig is exported this way to ensure that next/jest can load the Next.js config which is async
module.exports = createJestConfig(customJestConfig)
```

In a react component, I am using an external library:

```
import SyntaxHighlighter from "react-syntax-highlighter";
```

In my spec, I am mocking this external library as follows:

```
jest.mock('react-syntax-highlighter', () => ({
  __esModule: true, // -> to mock default imports
  SyntaxHighlighter: ({ children }) => <div data-testid="mock-syntax-highlighter">{children}</div>,
}));
```

I get following error when running jest:

```
 FAIL  src/app/components/atoms/global-markdown/GlobalMarkdown.spec.jsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'react-syntax-highlighter' from 'src/app/components/atoms/global-markdown/GlobalMarkdown.spec.jsx'

      2 | import { GlobalMarkdown } from './GlobalMarkdown'
      3 |
    > 4 | jest.mock('react-syntax-highlighter', () => ({
        |      ^
      5 |   __esModule: true,
      6 |   SyntaxHighlighter: ({ children }) => <div data-testid="mock-syntax-highlighter">{children}</div>,
      7 | }));

      at Resolver._throwModNotFoundError (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:427:11)
      at Object.mock (src/app/components/atoms/global-markdown/GlobalMarkdown.spec.jsx:4:6)
```

I don't get it, I thought this error should not appear since in the `jest.config.js`, I added: `moduleDirectories: ["node_modules"]`,

Mocking modules from my app works fine.